# Producer - consumer in Java. Отслеживание количества произведенных продуктов

Tags: java, многопоточность, шаблоны-проектирования

Доброго времени суток !

Перед тем, как задать вопрос опишу свою задачу *(это может помочь с ответом).*

Eсть `изображение`. Это изображение я разбиваю на `матрицу` изображений. И каждый элемент матрицы генерируется кодом. В последующем я должен каждый элемент записать в **БД**. Все работало и без потоков и этого паттерна, просто скорость записи была неудовлетворительной. (использовал `транзакции`, `синглетон - коннектор` и прочее)

Сделал все по вот [этому](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm) примеру.

В этом примере у него количество сделанных продуктов равна количеству принятых продуктов. То есть:

Тут он **положил** эти продукты 10 раз

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
cubbyhole.put(i);
}
```

А тут он их **принял** 10 раз

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            value = cubbyhole.get();
}
```

В моем же случае количество сфабрикованных элементов `n-нное`. 
Есть ли какие - нибудь способы как можно отследить количество сфабрикованных элементов ? Стараюсь сделать так, что бы каждый генерированный элемент сразу же записывался в **БД**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно при использовании паттерна producer-consumer количество производимых элементов неизвестно. Поэтому используют т.н. poison pill -- некоторый объект-маркер, который означает завершение генерации элементов. Часто в этом качестве используют `null`, однако зависит от задачи. Важно, что это некоторое значение, которое либо не встречается в производимых элементах, либо логически означает завершение генерации элементов (например, строка "END-OF-FILE" в конце файла). При этом если элементы в очередь кладут N продьюсеров, то при потреблении элементов нужно отслеживать количество полученных poison pill'ов -- процессинг будет завершен после того, как было получено N штук.

Пара примеров:

- http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/listings/IndexingService.java
- https://dzone.com/articles/producers-and-consumers-part-3

Есть другой вариант: очередь элементов должна поддерживать завершение работы. В дотнете примером служит метод `BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding()` и флаг `BlockingCollection<T>.IsCompleted`. К сожалению, не знаю, если ли в Джаве подобный API.

P.S. Также советую рассмотреть использование [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) в качестве очереди элементов. Это более "современный" подход, позволяющий отказаться от использования локов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ! Я кстати пример с BlockingQueue нашел первее, чем тот, по которому делаю сейчас. Подумал, что не разберусь с этим. Видимо надо будет разбираться. 

А с **poison pill** пример какой нибудь сможете показать ? Ссылку на туториал или что нибудь в этом духе.

Comment: @kxxko добавил в ответ пару ссылок.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ !

Есть возможность задать один вопрос в чате ? Он слишком маленький, что бы ради него создавать тему. Тоже по поводу потоков.

Comment: @kxxko куда зайти?

Comment: [Вот сюда](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26853/)